# Inside Function: Copy value from array or repeated access by index

Tags: c++, arrays, performance

I have a question regarding the efficiency/performance when accessing arrays inside functions.
Let's say I have a function that loops through an array with 5,000 elements. Inside that function, I access an array `X` multiple times at an index `X[k]`.
From a performance perspective, is it advantageous to assign the value at index k to a temporary variable in the loop, such as `tmpVal = X[k]`? In other words, can I increase the speed of execution by avoiding accessing an array at the same position over and over again?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you measured? Try it first (at highest optimization level), and measure the differences. Nonetheless, there's something called a cache. As far as your variable isn't `volatile` qualified, your compiler should be able to optimize better than you can. Still, measure first.

Comment: No, I haven't done that yet. But I will do in a minute. I thought there might be some rule of thumb. Thanks so far!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me prefix this by saying that what you're trying to achieve is a micro-optimization at best, and that you should be focus on making your code easy to follow, rather than trying to squeeze out extra performance here.

Realistically, there will be almost no difference between:

1. Accessing an element in an array by index, and
2. Accessing a copy on the stack.

Due to smart use of the processor's on-die caches, the first time you access the element of the array it will be copied into the cache and from there will be extremely fast access.

If you did create a temporary copy, you're copying your object to a new location, which will be more expensive (probably) than simply accessing the object inside the array.

Comment: Thank you already. Is pass-by-pointer to a double vs. passing a double by-value as function argument also an example for micro-optimization?

Comment: @mscnvrsy - Glad I could help. Yes, passing a double by pointer would also be a micro-optimization. In fact it is likely to make things worse! A `double` is typically 8 bytes (64 bits) in size, which is exactly the same as a pointer on an x64 PC (also 64 bits). That means that whether you pass by pointer, or pass a copy, you're always copying 8-bytes to the function. With a pointer however, your function will need to dereference it, which will mean it will take longer!

Answer (score 0):

in my view assigning a temporal variable to the index will only be of essence if you need to keep the value of any particular index at every instance and override that value for future instances .If not then upon execution the array execution is still as fast and efficient as possible.It does save time in looping large array sizes for values inside unless you know exactly the value and its index you want to access but if not all is well then